# Does Chrome view source get currently loaded page?

Tags: google-chrome

When you right click and select "view source" for a webpage within Google Chrome, does it make another request to the server for the source or does it give you the source of the page that is currently loaded?

To be more specific, if I went to a page and then view the source, would this look like 2 page views / requests to the webserver?

Answer (score 2):

It displays the source that was returned in the original http response. It doesn't show any DOM changes since the server response (e.g. if javascript alters the page).

Tested by: 
  Google search for 'time'
  Results show current time
  Wait 2 mins 
  View source, still shows original time
  Change the DOM with developer tools
  View source, still shows the original DOM